# Python click button on web page without selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, mechanize

So there is a button on a webpage that downloads a csv file after clicking it. In the past I have used selenium to do this, but given the current application of this script being ran on databricks I'd rather not use a web driver. However, when I inspect the button I see no URL or a JS function call. Here is what the html looks like:

```
<button id="exportReport" class="button">
                    Export Report                   
                </button> == $0
```

I would link the webpage, but it requires a log in. Is there any way I can simulate clicking this button via requests, mechanize, or beautiful soup?

Comment: Use the Chrome dev tools > Network tab. Click on the CSV button and see where the CSV comes from.

Comment: Perfect! Nice little trick, was able to get the api endpoint from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying my comment to the answer:

Use the Chrome dev tools (F12) > Network tab. Click the button on the web page to see where the CSV comes from:

[image: Chrome Tools Network Tab]

Answer (score 0):

try with mechanize:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')] 

url = 'https://www.your_url'
br.open(url, timeout=10.0)

# If exist any form
br.select_form(nr= 0)
br.form['name_of_form']=str('text_to_search')

# click on the button and saved it into a variable
data = br.submit()
```

Another way would be to try with Selenium, in case it is a javascript button:

```
data=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='exportReport']")
data=browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", data)
```

I hope you have success.